# How to use HTML tags in Symfony flash message

Tags: php, html, symfony, twig

working with Symfony 2.7 I would like to include HTML in a flash message:

```
class MyController extends Controller {
    public function someAction(Request $request) {
        ...
        $this->addFlash('success', $tranlator->trans('some.success.msg', array(), 'app'));
        ...
    }
}


// app.yml
some:
    success:
         msg: Text with some <strong>HTML</strong>
```

This creates a Flash Message

```
Text with some <strong>HTML</strong>
```

instead of

> Text with some **HTML**

Within my own Twig template I would use the `raw` filter, to display the HTML code directly instead of the escaped version. But how can I achive the same within `addFlash(...)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this cannot be done directly. But you can tweak where you are showing the message using some html and css.

Like:

**In setting the flash message:**

```
$this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', array('type' => 'success', 'title' => 'Done!', 'message' => 'OK! It is done!'));
```

**And in twig file:**

```
{% for msg in app.session.flashbag.get('notice') %}
<div class="alert alert-{{ msg.type }}">
    <strong>{{ msg.title }}</strong><br/>{{ msg.message }}
</div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Hi! I found out, that the default base layout I was using did not used the `raw` filter to display the messages. So I just created a new base layout by extending the old one, added the `raw` filter and it worked. Thanks for the hint!

Comment: I've -1 this answer, since the `FlashBagInterface` clearly states that `$message` should be a string. I like the workaround, but it is actually a clean hack.

Comment: No problems for the minus :-). I think it will be great you put the minus knowing that the solution was indeed a hack (as it required) and served the purpose. Best of luck.

Comment: Please note that the solution you proposed is not covered by our BC promise. This means that if you do not use an interface in a way that it states it can be used (i.e. given by the argument types in the docblock), you are on your own and risk to break your application even when updating to a new patch release.

Answer (score 13):

Not sure i really understand your question. If this is not what you're asking just say it and I will remove this answer.
As said in [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/controller.html#flash-messages) you use

```
app.session.flashbag.get('success')
```

to retrieve your flash message.
Example :

```
{% for flash_message in app.session.flashbag.get('success') %}
        {{ flash_message|raw }}
{% endfor %}
```